# Receiving Error: Class Object is missing in schema: actions.actions

Tags: nearprotocol

I am trying to sign transaction using "near-api-js" library.
Transaction is from [near guest book](https://near.github.io/wallet-selector/) using wallet-selector for near wallet that I am building.

```
const signedTransaction = await nearAPI.transactions.signTransaction(receiverId, nonce, actions, blockHash, signer, accountId, networkId)
```

I have also tried to use:

```
const transaction = nearAPI.transactions.createTransaction(signerId, publicKey, receiverId, nonce, actions, blockHash)
const signedTransaction = await nearAPI.transactions.signTransaction(transaction, accountId, networkId)
```

error I am getting:
[image: error]

my actions in transaction object contains

```
    "actions": [
        {
            "functionCall": {
                "methodName": "addMessage",
                "args": [123,34,116,101,120,116,34,58,34,97,100,115,102,34,125],
                "gas": {
                    "negative": 0,
                    "words": [56090624,447034,0],
                    "length": 2,
                    "red": null
                },
                "deposit": {
                    "negative": 0,
                    "words": [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                    "length": 1,
                    "red": null
                }
            },
            "enum": "functionCall"
        }
    ]
```

[image: Transaction Object]

I am using `"near-api-js": "^0.45.1"`

Any idea about the error?

Comment: There is a know issue in near-api-js: https://docs.near.org/tools/near-api-js/faq#class-x-is-missing-in-schema-publickey
can you see the workaround mentioned solves it for you?